# Prove that this graph is planar

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

How do you prove that this graph is or isn't planar? Euler's inequality is correct here. It seems like there is a $K_{3,3}$ subgraph, but I can't find it. How can I check whether this graph is planar or not?

[image]

Comment: Answers to the [Stack Overflow question "How to check if a Graph is a Planar Graph or not?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854711/how-to-check-if-a-graph-is-a-planar-graph-or-not) lists graph libraries which should answer this quickly for you.  But I don't see that anyone provides this service on the web, sadly.

Comment: This is a multigraph. Perhaps removing some of the multiple edges will make it easier to work with. You can easily add them back if/after you find a planar drawing.

Comment: @bof I think rather then writing everything it text it would be easier to draw K3,3 on picture (if graph is not planar) / draw plane graph (if graph is planar)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One crude drawing deserves another.

[image]

In general if you are trying to find if a graph is planar or not, you first start playing around trying to find a $K_{3,3}$ or $K_5$ subgraph (or [minor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagner's_theorem)). If you struggle to find one, the graph might be planar, so then you play around trying to find a planar embedding. Alternate these two methods of playing accordingly until something gives.

Comment: The subgraph of 6 colored points is planar. Just move the right-most green dot down the page, below the right-most red dot. Is this just to illustrate the search method?

Comment: @user254665 see the image in my question and in this answer - Mike Pierce highlighted edges of subgraph with bold black line. And you can check that his subgraph is K3,3 (which is not planar)